# Global variable not getting set

Tags: java, swing, static, global-variables, key-bindings

I am using swing and have a function ( CreateAndShowGUI() ) which listens for key press of Up,Left,Right & Down . Now whenever any of this key is pressed , I am setting the key_pressed flag to True . The key_pressed flag is a Global variable.

Now when i run the program and press any key (up,left,right,down) , i can see the key_pressed variable being set to True  .But when I try to access the same in main , the value of this key_pressed is false .Can anyone help me on where I am wrong ?

```
public class table1  {

public static class Global {
   // public static boolean key_pressed=false;
    public static int[][] a={{2,8,32,64},{2,4,16,16},{16,128,8,64},{2,4,8,16}};

}
 public static boolean key_pressed=false;
 public static JTable table;
 public static JFrame frame=new JFrame("FrameDemo");
 public static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        //frame = 
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(875, 800));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon("menu.jpg").getImage());
        JLabel emptyLabel = new JLabel("");
        emptyLabel.setFocusable(true);

        Action left_action = new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                key_pressed=true;
                System.out.println("left");
                //do nothing
            }
        };
        Action right_action = new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                key_pressed=true;
                System.out.println("right");
                //do nothing
            }
        };
        Action up_action = new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                key_pressed=true;
                System.out.println("up");
                //do nothing
            }
        };
        Action down_action = new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("down");
                //do nothing
            }
        };
        emptyLabel.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("LEFT"),"left");
        emptyLabel.getActionMap().put("left", left_action);
        emptyLabel.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("RIGHT"),"right");
        emptyLabel.getActionMap().put("right", right_action);
        emptyLabel.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("UP"),"up");
        emptyLabel.getActionMap().put("up", up_action);
        emptyLabel.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("DOWN"),"down");
        emptyLabel.getActionMap().put("down", down_action);
        emptyLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(875, 800));


        //frame.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        Font f = new Font("serif", Font.PLAIN, 15);
        JLabel score_area = new JLabel();

        score_area.setBounds(870-130,00, 130, 50);
        score_area.setText("sample text");

        emptyLabel.add(score_area);

        /*JTable t1=addtable(Global.a);
        emptyLabel.add(t1);
        t1.setBounds(0, 80, 875,875-80);*/

        //pnl.add(t1);
        frame.add(emptyLabel);
        frame.invalidate();
        frame.validate();
        frame.repaint();
        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();


        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

  public static JTable addtable(int[][] a)
  {
      System.out.println("add game_gui entered");
      //a[0][0] +=1;      
      System.out.println("a value "+a[0][0]);
      String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
              "Last Name",
              "Sport","sample"
              };
       Object[][] data1= new Object[4][4];
       for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
           for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++)
           {
               data1[i][j]=(Object)a[i][j];
           }
       }
       Font f = new Font("serif", Font.PLAIN, 55);
       table = new JTable( data1, columnNames);/*{
           Object x;
           JLabel label;
           @Override
           public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer,
                     int row, int column) {
                x=table.getModel().getValueAt(row, column);
             //  System.out.println(x+","+row+","+column);
                   label = (JLabel) super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
                  if(x ==(Object)2)
                  {

                      System.out.println(x+" "+row+" " +column);
                     label.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                  } else if(x==(Object)32) {
                     label.setBackground(Color.gray);
                  }
                  else if(x==(Object)
                          16) {
                     label.setBackground(Color.blue);
                  }
                  return label;
               };
       };*/
       table.setRowHeight(125);
       table.setEnabled(false);
       DefaultTableCellRenderer dtcr = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();  
        dtcr.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER); 
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(dtcr);
        int  x=((Integer)table.getValueAt(0, 0)).intValue();
        System.out.println("sdfsfsdfsfds"+x);
        if(x==55)
            System.out.println("hahahah "+x);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(dtcr);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellRenderer(dtcr);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellRenderer(dtcr);
        DefaultTableCellRenderer dtcr1 = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
        dtcr1.setBackground(Color.cyan);


        table.repaint();

        table.setFont(f);

        return table;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
      //key_pressed=true;
      createAndShowGUI();
      while(true)
      {
          //System.out.println(key_pressed);
          if(key_pressed)
          {
              key_pressed=false;
              System.out.println("Hello");
          }
      }
     }}
```

Comment: try to define it as `public static volatile boolean key_pressed=false;`

Comment: Let's start with, `static` is not your friend...

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you are trying to achieve using this `key_pressed` boolean value?

Comment: @Parasu : I was trying to check for key press event . Once any of the 4 arrow key were pressed , the key_pressed was set, and there are other method which are to be followed.

Comment: @kiran If you are trying to do some job in a different thread(is it single or multiple?) based on the keypress, then you could simply put something into an ArrayBlockingQueue, so that the other thread could wait on the call to `queue.take()`. The other thread, will take one by one and could do its job, so that you will not miss a press.

Comment: @Parasu : Thanks for the suggestion . I will surely look into it .

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Lashane : Using volatile to key_pressed solves this issue .

Answer (score 0):

Even though the use of volatile solves the problem, I think a correct (and recommended) use os instances and classes in your main would also correct the problem.

My first thought when I saw your code was "Why doesn't he use the name of the classes to access methods and class attributes?" and the second "Shouldn't the inner class be declared as singleton better than static?". I wonder if my second thought was accurate since I do not know if is more efficient or "better" use static or singleton, but certainly it fix the problem too.

Cheers